# Mozilla HTML5 video and canvas problems

Tags: html, firefox, video, canvas, z-index

I have full screen canvas and i draw video on it. I hide video behind canvas with z-index. When I resize my browser to a size smaller than the original size of the video scrollbars appear so I can scroll and see the rest of the video I don't like that so I solved the problem by resizing the video to a small size. This solved the problem in chrome, opera and IE
but in Mozilla this small size video appears over my canvas so I have white screen with small video on it. I don't understand why because video z-index is still lower than z-index of the canvas. Any idea how to solve this?

Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/Ag3LvHUV

Comment: It would help if you showed us the HTML code for the canvas and the video as well as the styles involved.

Comment: I added the code to my original post.

Comment: This looks like it should work... Is there an actual page showing the problem?  When I try your pasted source in Firefox I don't see any issues....

Comment: I seems like when mozilla resizes video it puts it infornt of the canvas an ignores the z-index

Comment: Changed the code same problem.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried putting the canvas after the video element in the DOM then rearranging that way?

```
<body >
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <video id="v" loop>
            <source src='content/bbb-mp4.mp4' type='video/mp4;'>
            <source src='content/bbb-ogv.ogg' type='video/ogg;'>
        </video>
        <canvas id="c"></canvas>
        <div id="mainCon">
            <div id="main" onmouseover="this.style.opacity= 0.8;" onmouseout="this.style.opacity= 0.1;">
                <h1>Test</h1>
                Video background
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes is the same thing. Here are the screen shoots http://i.imgur.com/Tss8Y.png  and http://i.imgur.com/RUI02.jpg

Comment: My latest version of the code http://pastebin.com/HejgHY7i still the same problem.